# PHP Dynamic URL Folder Paths

Tags: php

I am trying to create a login and admin section to my project, however, I do not want to actually have the folders (ROOT/login/) and (ROOT/admin/) on the server.  Instead, when someone navigates to http://localhost/admin/, it instead includes another file to the existing index.php.

I know how to check for _GET and _POST, but that doesn't seem like the route I am looking for as I do not index.php?SOME_VALUE.  Instead, I am looking for an actual folder (in the URL) that doesn't really exist on the server.

I hope I am making sense.  Here is an example:

```
$conf_site_url = http://localhost/

if 
     $conf_site_url + $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] === 'http://localhost/admin/'  
then 
    include(/driver/views/admin/page.php);
else if 
    $conf_site_url + $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] === 'http://localhost/login/' 
then
    include(/driver/views/login.php);
else
    include(driver/view/site.php);
```

Basically, if admin/ or login/ are appended to the URL, then include a different file from a nested folder, however, if nothing, then include the standard site.php file.

Comment: Why not use `.htaccess` for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made some changes to the codes.

```
$conf_site_url = "http://localhost";
if($conf_site_url."".$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] === 'http://localhost/admin/'  )
{
    include("/driver/views/admin/page.php");    
}else if($conf_site_url."".$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] === 'http://localhost/login/' ){
    include("/driver/views/login.php");
}else{
    include("driver/view/site.php");
}
```

You should not forget the htaccess file.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information provided by ahmetarpaci's response, adding a .htaccess file with:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php [PT,L]
```

does the trick.